# Refresh my new plasmoid - reparse source

Tags: kde-plasma, plasmoid

I'm learning how to develop Kde Plasma 5 plasmoids, and testing it with a small widget, consistent of just two qmls. I read some information sources, like https://techbase.kde.org or https://api.kde.org/frameworks/ and created a package structure and sources for my test plasmoid, which looks like this:

```
$ ls -lR test
test:
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 3 alberto alberto 4096 nov 26 14:28 contents
-rw-r--r-- 1 alberto alberto  459 nov 26 14:28 metadata.desktop

test/contents:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 alberto alberto 4096 nov 26 14:33 ui

test/contents/ui:
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 alberto alberto 275 nov 26 14:28 main.qml
-rw-r--r-- 1 alberto alberto 465 nov 26 14:33 RootContainer.qml
```

The RootContainer is just the fullRepresentation of the widget, and contains only a label with the text "prueba1". So, as i read in the documentation, i used the command *plasmapkg2* to install the widget as follows:

```
$ plasmapkg2 --install test
pluginname:  "org.matrixland.test"
Generated  "/home/xxx/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids//kpluginindex.json"  ( 3  plugins)
/home/xxx/ProgramaciÃ³n/proyectos/plasmoides/test instalado con Ã©xito
```

Then, i can use it in the kde desktop and everything is fine. It is shown in the desktop, with the text label.

But now, if i change the text of the label, "prueba2", and i remove and reinstall the plugin as follows

```
$ plasmapkg2 --remove test 
Constructing a KPluginInfo object from old style JSON. Please use kcoreaddons_desktop_to_json() for "" instead of kservice_desktop_to_json() in your CMake code.
Calling KPluginInfo::property("X-KDE-PluginInfo-Name") is deprecated, use KPluginInfo::pluginName() in "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/packagestructure/plasma_packagestructure_share.so" instead.
Constructing a KPluginInfo object from old style JSON. Please use kcoreaddons_desktop_to_json() for "" instead of kservice_desktop_to_json() in your CMake code.
Calling KPluginInfo::property("X-KDE-PluginInfo-Name") is deprecated, use KPluginInfo::pluginName() in "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/plasma/packagestructure/plasma_packagestructure_share.so" instead.
Generated  "/home/xxx/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids//kpluginindex.json"  ( 2  plugins)
/home/xxx/ProgramaciÃ³n/proyectos/plasmoides/test desinstalado con Ã©xito

>xxx@eleanor:~/Programación/proyectos/plasmoides$ plasmapkg2 --install test
pluginname:  "org.matrixland.test"
Generated  "/home/alberto/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids//kpluginindex.json"  ( 3  plugins)
/home/alberto/ProgramaciÃ³n/proyectos/plasmoides/test instalado con Ã©xito
```

If now, i add it again to the desktop, i see the old text instead of the new one. I checked in the */home/xxx/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/org.matrixland.test* directory that the source is up to date and refreshed, so i can't guess why am i obtaining the old text instead of the new one.

Obviously my problem is that none of the changes i make in the qml is reflected in the widget, not only text changes. I don't know if i am doing something wrong, or if i must do anything else to update the widget. Can anybody help me with that?

[image: KDE and Qt version info]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the old QML is "cached" still. You'll need to restart plasmashell in order to see the changes.

```
killall plasmashell; kstart5 plasmashell
```

I used [this script](https://github.com/Zren/plasma-applet-lib/blob/master/reinstall) to reinstall applets when I want to test live. When I want to test quickly though, I'll use `plasmoidviewer` with:

```
plasmoidviewer -a package -l bottomedge -f horizontal
```

like in [this script](https://github.com/Zren/plasma-applet-todolist/blob/master/run).

Comment: thank you, @Zren. Now i'm using plasmoidviewer to see my progress as i write my own plasmoid. It's very useful.

Comment: Scripts now available at <https://github.com/Zren/plasma-applet-todolist>